# Passing a struct to a thread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

Sorry for the second post, I find threads really complicated..
I am trying to pass a struct to a thread parameter, but I get the error:

```
 error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
 printf("%d\n", assembly->size);
```

I am not sure how to fix it, here is my main code(**test.c**).

```
#include "test.h"


int main()
{

    assembly.size = 10;

    pthread_t thread_tid;
    pthread_create(&thread_tid, NULL, foo, &assembly);

    pthread_join(thread_tid, NULL);

return 0;
}
```

The function that the thread calls(**test1.c**):

```
void * foo(void *param)
    {
        struct factory *assembly = param;
        printf("%d\n", assembly->size);
        return NULL;
    }
```

My header file which holds the struct definition(**test.h**):

```
#ifndef TEST1_H
#define TEST1_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "test1.c"

struct factory{
    int size;
    int products_per_box;
    int products_to_assemble;
};
struct factory assembly;

void * foo(void *param);

#endif
```

Comment: Would be handy to point out what line the compiler has an error on?

Comment: Is `foo` in the same source file as `main`? Can you please state explicitly where the functions are defined and what the file names are? Also, why are you including a C file in your header file?

Comment: Declareing variables without `extern` in header files is not good because it may lead to linker error due to multiple definition.

Comment: Well, you have test1.c included *before* the definition of `struct factory`. So of course at this line `printf("%d\n", assembly->size)`, the definition of `struct factory` is not known. Buy why oh why are you including a C file into header file? There are cases where this is done if you really know what you are doing. But beginner programmers should just never do that.

Comment: @kaylum. okay, well I was using it because I couldn't get foo to be read, turns out I was linking them incorrectly during compilation. Now after correctly linking and getting rid of the C in the header file, it works and my error is gone.

Comment: As usual, if you had bothered to actually extract a minimal example, you would have found yourself that e.g. the threading is a red herring. In other words, your error is firstly not uncommon and secondly it has nothing to do with multithreading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are *`#including`* your other `.c` file to make them into 1 compilation unit (which is wrong). **After preprocessing, the code in the `test.c` compilation unit will be something like**:

```
/* contents of <stdio.h> */
/* contents of <stdlib.h> */
/* contents of <pthread.h> */

void * foo(void *param)
{
    struct factory *assembly = param;
    printf("%d\n", assembly->size);   // this line needs knowledge...
    return NULL;
}

struct factory{                    
    int size;
    int products_per_box;
    int products_to_assemble;
};                                    // ...that is available only after this 
                                      // line in this compilation unit



struct factory assembly;
void * foo(void *param);

int main()
{

    assembly.size = 10;

    pthread_t thread_tid;
    pthread_create(&thread_tid, NULL, foo, &assembly);

    pthread_join(thread_tid, NULL);

return 0;
}
```

Notice yet? C compiler works from top to down. At the line `printf("%d\n", assembly->size);` the compiler does not know of what type the member `size` is, nor does it know whether the `struct factory`  even has a member so called.

What you need to do is to have `test1.c` `#include "test.h"` and compile `test1.c` separately:

```
#include "test.h"  

void * foo(void *param)
{
    struct factory *assembly = param;
    printf("%d\n", assembly->size);
    return NULL;
}
```

Also, you'd want to move the declaration of `struct factory assembly` *out of the header file*, into the `main.c`, or otherwise every single compilation unit that has that header file included would get that variable declared.

And then you can compile and link them together using one command for example by:

```
% gcc test.c main.c -o program
```

or by compiling each separately

```
% gcc -c test.c
% gcc -c main.c
% gcc -o program test.o main.o
```

Comment: You have forgot to mention that the line `struct assembly * factory` needs to be removed from the header file.

Comment: I see you have made an edit - but now this statement "Now your code is essentially" is factually incorrect

Comment: @EdHeal and how is it factually incorrect? the "Now your code is essentially" refers to what we know about OP's code and also generates the exact same error.

Comment: The "now you code is essentially" is a cut'n'paste job with the OP post (i.e. replace the #includes with the code). You have *silently* modified this code in your post.

Comment: But you have not cut'n'paste - You have edited out a line of code that should have been pasted.

Answer (score -1):

1) Remove this line from `test.h` - You do not need it

```
  struct factory assembly;
```

2) In `main` add the line just before `assembly.size=10;`

```
   struct factory assembly;
```

3) Add a cast i.e. change

```
 struct factory *assembly = param;
```

to

```
struct factory *assembly = (struct factory *)param;
```

4) As others have pointed out - delete this line

```
#include "test1.c"
```

*In general you only include header files*

Comment: because none of these was an answer to why the only error was happening, nor fix them.

Comment: It fixes the problem - the poster is trying to pass `factory` into the thread creation.